# How do I limit CLOB column in SQL?

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, hql

In my table has a field of type CLOB, it stores a part in text and some images converted into binary code. This gets very heavy on the query. I would like to know how I can in SQL or HQL if possible remove the binary code from the field in the query.

In Oracle I can limit the size of the field like this:

`Select dbms_lob.substr ( sost_tx , 4000, 1 ) FROM sost;`

But what I really need is to bring only part of the text from the column.

Some method that can identify the beginning and end of an expression and remove it.

I looked it up and found this method that can alter the value of the column only between the beginning and end of an expression, that's exactly what I need, only on Select not Update. Is there a way to do that?

````
SET @OpenTag = '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">'

UPDATE Products_Joined
SET TechSpecs  = STUFF(TechSpecs ,
                       CHARINDEX(@OpenTag, TechSpecs ,1)  + LEN(@OpenTag),
                            CHARINDEX('</script>',TechSpecs ,1)-(CHARINDEX(@OpenTag, TechSpecs ,1)  + LEN(@OpenTag)), 
                       'New Text')```
````

Comment: *"In my table has a field of type CLOB, it stores a part in text and some images converted into binary code. This gets very heavy on the query."* Now you know why you shouldn't be using the database as file storage for "big" files, as the database is not really designed for that.

Comment: Also see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: If you have any design discretion consider using S3, file system, etc. to store the image file, with only the link/path to the file in the database.

Comment: I know, but it was the only alternative to the purpose of this application.

Comment: Honestly, the problem to me doesn't seem that you're storing images in your database, but you have a single column that contains part text, part ... I'm guessing binary data base64 encoded or something? How do you tell where the text part stops and the binary part begins?

Comment: @eaolson The code always start with this tag: '<img src="data:image' and ends with '>'. I updated my question for better understanding.